# Scrolling table in 100% Div inside table

Tags: html

I've got an outer div with a 2x2 table in it, which I want to keep 100% of the page, it should not generate page scrollbars.

Inside one of the top cells, there is another table inside a div, how can I make the inner table scroll inside the div such that the outer table doesn't expand past the page boundaries.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LV29h/

```
    <div style="width: 100%;">
<table id="main" class="outer-surround" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
        <td style="">
            <div id="top" style="background-color: lightpink; border-spacing: 0px; overflow: hidden;">


                <table style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="40">
                                <a href="#">ABC</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td><td > <a href="#">ABC</a> </td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 1px;"><div style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 400px; display: inline-block;">Test</div></td>
        <td><div style="background-color: yellow; height: 400px; display: block;">Test</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Table inside 'top' shouldn't force the page to scroll, it should scroll within 'top' div.

Answer (score 0):

Well tables cannot break so they always force the upper element to scroll, except you do overflow: hidden but then important data are not displayed at all.

Wether shortcut / wrap / fix your table col width and content size so the context cannot get too large or if you are aiming for the data to appear in the next row you have to use left floating  with some margin.